# dynamic editing json strings using jq

Tags: json, bash, environment-variables, sh, jq

Can I make a json structure dynamically editable storing the json data back and forth in a shell string using the jq tool.

for example what I was trying was to add a field in a structure like in this working code:

```
echo '{"a":{"b":1}}' | jq -c '.a |= .+ {c:2}'
{"a":{"b":1,"c":2}}
```

But using a shell fucntion like this:

```
jq_add () {
 eval $1=\"$(eval echo \$$1 | $JQ --argjson q1 "$(printf '\"%s\"'     "$2")" --argjson q2 "$(printf '\"%s\"' "$3")" '.[$q1] |= .+ $q2')\"
}

v='{"a":{"b":1}}'
jq_add v "a" "{c:2}"
echo $v
```

The answer is: 
**jq: error (at :1): object ({"b":1}) and array (["{c:2}"]) cannot be added**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you adopt a significantly less error-prone strategy. I am not sure about the wisdom of any of this, but the following achieves most of what you seem to be trying to do.  In any case, please note that `--argjson x v` expects `v` to be valid JSON: `{c:2}` is not valid JSON.

```
#!/bin/bash

JQ=jq

function jq_add {
   $JQ --argjson q1 "$1"  --argjson q2 "$2"  '.[$q1] += $q2'
}


v='{"a":{"b":1}}'
v=$(echo "$v" | jq_add '"a"' '{"c":2}')
echo "$v"
```

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!